# AWS API authorizer include body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to validate request in API Gateway based on its body? I need to calculate SHA1 hash of the body to validate the sender - Facebook messenger events... Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApiGateway does not support passing complete body to custom authorizer. 
One option is to have two level of authentication - first just based on header/query parameter ( which api gateway support ) and enough to detect spoof senders. Second can be SHA1 hash based on complete body which you can implement in your backend

Comment: And if i keep open API, could I somehow tell the gateway to block a sender of spoofed messages?

Comment: One way to restrict access without authorizer to use resource policy 
 ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html ) - not sure if it can help detect spoof senders for you.

Comment: Another option is to have two level of authentication - first just based on header/query parameter ( which api gateway support ) and enough to detect spoof senders. Second can be SHA1 hash based on complete body which you can implement in your backend.

Comment: Yh thats what I started working on yesterday actually. Do you want to put it in your answer so I can accept it? :)